# Error when calling Rscript from an R session: .libPaths() is "semi" inherited

Tags: r, linux

I have a Rscript written that should be executed using `R/3.5.1`. Let's call it `test.R`

```
#!/opt/apps/R/3.5.1/bin/Rscript
Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
print("miao")
.libPaths()
```

Most of my work, however, is on `R/3.6.1`. The goal is to perform a small task in `R/3.5.1`, to avoid some compatibility issues between packages.
I can directly call this script from bash with no problems, regardless which R version I load:

```
(jupyter) cfan@budweiser:~$ module load R/3.6.1
(jupyter) cfan@budweiser:~$ which R
/opt/apps/R/3.6.1/bin/R
(jupyter) cfan@budweiser:~$ which Rscript 
/opt/apps/R/3.6.1/bin/Rscript
(jupyter) cfan@budweiser:~$ test.R 
[1] "/opt/apps/R/3.5.1/lib/R"
[1] "miao"
[1] "/bar/cfan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5"
[2] "/opt/apps/R/3.5.1/lib/R/library"
```

However, this is not true if I call this script from with `R/3.6.1`

```
(jupyter) cfan@budweiser:~$ R --vanilla
> system("test.R")
WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME
[1] "/opt/apps/R/3.5.1/lib/R"
[1] "miao"
[1] "/bar/cfan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6"
[2] "/opt/apps/R/3.5.1/lib/R/library"
```

The first hint of the problem comes from `WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME`. But `R_HOME` was ignored so it didn't cause an error, and the outcome of `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")` remains unchanged. However, the outcome of `.libPaths()` is changed. One of the paths was set correctly to `3.5.1`, but the path to my personal lib was inherited from the "parent" R session, which was `3.6.1` instead. How will I be able to call a "fresh" child R session that is completely independent of the current session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do looks circular: calling R from R via `system()` in the last call.  If in doubt, *just prefix the path* to the binary directory of the R you want.  No more, no less.

#### Demo with my default R

```
edd@rob:~$ Rscript /tmp/test.R 
[1] "/usr/lib/R"
[1] "miao"
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"  
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"           
edd@rob:~$
```

#### Demo with R-devel in another directory

```sh
edd@rob:~$ PATH="/usr/local/lib/R-devel/bin/:$PATH" Rscript /tmp/test.R 
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R-devel/lib/R"
[1] "miao"
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R-devel/lib/R/library"
edd@rob:~$
```

Note that "all I do" is tell the shell to find another `Rscript`. The rest happens within R.

Comment: The situation I'm in is different. My entire pipeline is written in R. Therefore, I prefer to call a R script using `system` within the pipeline.

Comment: a) Then you may have a self-inflicted problem because if you are calling R from R and you will not be able to undo 3.6.1 when you call 3.5.1 as 3.6.1 'owns' some environment variables such as `R_HOME`.  b)  I doubt you really "must" use `system()`. You can always resort to shell wrappers.  c)  Anyway, this makes it clearer that the problem is more or less of your making. d)  Remember that you cannot remove paths from `.libPaths()` either (though IIRC that may change in r-devel).

Comment: is it possible to invoke Rscript from R in a way that doesn't pass any environment variable? or invoke something like a non-login shell? Thanks! I wasn't sure what you mean by solving to shell wrappers. I'm writing a R package so the starting point has to be within R. May I ask how I should implement a shell wrapper?

Comment: No because R is built throughout to support _exactly_ what I showed you: start with the PATH to obtain `R_HOME`, derive everything that is needed from there.  You now assume "oh maybe I can just reset some values..." and it turns out that that assummption simply does not hold. Sorry.